# Request the parameters of textfields of flex document

Tags: java, apache-flex, servlets, flex4

I am an amateur in flex and I want to authenticate a flex user log in in servlet. How do I request the parameters of text fields of flex document?

Comment: Don't worry, I was never dissatisfied. :)  Mostly because I care not whether you get an answer - it's your problem.  ;)

Comment: What have you done already? What is your problem? Have you created text fields? Did you manage to send request? Did you manage to handle response? Do you have a problem of passing request parameters?